# iAd didFailToReceiveAdWithError called before viewDidLoad

Tags: iad

I have an iAdBannerView instaniated by IB and connected properly along with the delegate. When I start up the app, I see didFailToReceiveAdWithError being called before the viewDidLoad method. In the stack trace I see [ADBannerView _sanitizeAndForwardErrorToDelegate:].

This doesn't seem quite right, but I have to ask, is this normal behavior?

The bannerViewDidLoadAd is never called and yes, I'm in the US and connected to network.

This is happening in both the simulator and the iOS device.